sbom not generated when using cyclonedx-gomod
I'm trying to use cyclonedx-gomod tools to generate a sbom for a repository, this one for example. I run this pipeline:
steps:
  - type: Command
    name: "go version"
    command: |
       go version
  - type: Command
    name: "install cyclonedx-gomod"
    command: |
      GOBIN=$(pwd) go install github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gomod@v0.8.3
  - type: Command
    name: "run cyclonedx-gomod"
    command: |
      ./cyclonedx-gomod -licenses -std -output bom.json -json

The version of go is go1.16.5 linux/amd64 which is supported in the v0.8.3, the pipeline is failed with the error :
** generating sbom failed: failed to enumerate modules: listing vendored modules failed: exit status 1   
Step 'run cyclonedx-gomod' failed with exit code: '1', please check the commands on the spec file.

How can I resolve this error?

Have you tried to search existing project issues and requests? https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gomod/issues
